# What are some synonymous phrases for the phrase "Turning Criminal"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, synonyms

I need suggestions for different ways to say "turning criminal," as in "He began turning criminal, committing illegal acts instead of abiding by the law."

Answer (score 3):

If you're going for subtlety, try

> He began to **cross the line**, committing illegal acts instead of upholding the law...

Other phrases you could substitute here for the bold text would be:

- **turn to crime**
- **cross over**
- **cross into the dark side** (pop culture reference)

Edit: if the character was also homosexual you could make a double entendre with the phrase **batting for the other team**

Edit2: triple entendre if he was into baseball.

Comment: Hahahaha +1 for *triple entendre*.

Comment: @DanBron: [This is priceless](http://genius.com/posts/71-Don-t-ask-me-how-the-elusive-triple-entendre-in-hip-hop). _"The triple entendre is an elusive-ass motherf****r."_

Comment: @TusharRaj That is great.  I'd +1 your comment, but I'm all out of +1s today.

Answer (score 1):

Become **[crooked](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crooked)**

> adjective
>   4. not straightforward; dishonest.

(dictionary.reference.com)

Almost always meant in a criminal way. (i.e. a crook.)

Answer (score 0):

> Resorting to criminality.

This amounts to another way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since *recidivism* means *returning* to crime, it seems to me that the *initial* turning would be;

***cidivism***

"He was a paragon of propriety until he turned into a ***cidivist***"